# Nhibernate IList mapping to sub child table

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Parent
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name  { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<string> Values { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {

    }
}
```

ORM mapping file:

```
<class name="Testing.Models.Parent" table="Parent"  >
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <list name="Values" table="ChildValue" inverse="true" >
      <key column="ParentId" />
      <index column="Sequence" type="System.Int32"/>
      <element column="Value" type="System.String"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

But while testing with save of parent entity, it only inserts into parent table.
ChildValue table is not inserted with any record, though I provided the Values .

I found somewhere inverse has to be true, even with that it is not working.

[update: insert code]
Create method

```
public IList<Parent> Create(IList<Parent> entities)
{
 using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
       foreach (var entity in entities)
         {
            session.Save(entity);
        }
         return entities;
    }
}
```

ISessionFactory is injected using Unity and configured as

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISessionFactory),
                new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory());
```

While nhibernate configuration is like(in app.config)

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"  >
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect,NHibernate</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
      <!-- set show_sql property to false on production-->
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <mapping assembly="Testing"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Test method which creates entities is

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestCreate()
        {
            IList<Parent> entities = new List<Parent>();
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
            {
                var entity = TestHelper.CreateEntity<Parent>();
                entity.Values = new List<string>();
                entity.Values.Add("Values" + index);
                entities.Add(entity);
            }
            entities = instance.Create(entities);

            VerifyPickList(entities, "Create");

            Assert.AreEqual(5, (int)TestHelper.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" +
                " [dbo].[Parent]"), "Create is wrong.");
        }
```

[update 2: sql]

```
-- parent table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRimary Key,
    [Name] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
)

-- child table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChildValue](
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Parent__D099C8FD03317E3D] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParentId] ASC,
    [Value] ASC
)


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildValue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_plv_pl] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildValue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [pk_plv_pl]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important here is to **NOT** use **`inverse="true"`**.

```
<list name="Values" table="ChildValue" 
    // inverse="true" is NO OPTION for element lists
    inverse="false" // inverse="false" or nothing
  >
  <key column="ParentId" />
  <index column="Sequence" type="System.Int32"/>
  <element column="Value" type="System.String"/>
 </list>
```

The point is, that NHibernate takes this setting as: "The other end will care about persistence..." which is ok, if there is a class, the `<one-to-many>`. But not ok, if there is `<element>`

Class *(mapped as `one-to-many`)* is first level citizen, which can care about persistence... *string* cannot

This code should now do INSERT into both tables:

```
var parent = Parent { Name = "abc" };
parent.Values  = new List<string> { "testValue" };
session.Save(parent);
```

Check the doc, e.g.

- [6.6. Sorted Collections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-sorted)

with an example:

```
<set name="Aliases" table="person_aliases" sort="natural">
    <key column="person"/>
    <element column="name" type="String"/>
</set>
```

Check this article for more details:

- [inverse = “true” example and explanation](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/) by Mkyong

Comment: Ya tried and looked at that, even after setting nothing or inverse=false, it is  not saving in child table. (Using log4Net) The sql generated by Nhibernate has only one query to insert into parent table nothing else.

Comment: Could you extend your question with a statement which you are using to create and persist entity?

Comment: Yes checked with inverse="false" and nothing too including cascade="all". I have checked every possible combination of these. Waiting for favorable response. Thanks you so much for your time.

Comment: I tested your scenario *(same entities, and same mapping - but **`inverse="false"`**)* - it is working. NHibernate is now inserting into child Value Table. maybe just add `session.Flush()` after *session.Save(..)*. But this mapping is correct. Simply, in this scenario, the **`inverse="false"`** *(the default value)* is the way.. and that will instruct NHibernate to properly insert all the stuff

Comment: I used your code! as is... just added session.Flush() after session.Save(). And the setting must be **inverse="false"**

Comment: Did you try the multiple entities. If I try to save single entity it is working but for next time flush cause sequence cannot be duplicate, that is index is not updating for sequence column.

Comment: YES! I used your code... I used **5** entities. That is the progress! great that the first one is working. Could you show SQL Script CREATE TABLE? Simply.. `<index>` is managed by NHiberante. It must be editable column... no identity,.. Also, there cannot be any constraint over this sequence column (only like parent, sequence are unique together - but now I would suggest to remove any constraint)

Comment: updated, Oh yes there is constraint over value field to be unique with parentId.

Comment: The primary index is wrong. We need to have unique combination `( [ParentId] ASC,  [Sequence] ASC)`, not the  `( [ParentId] ASC,  [Value] ASC)` (because list could contain same string values...)

Comment: Wow, that's great. Really. Enjoy Mighty NHiberante. It is amazing tool ;)